# Paths in a Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $s$ and $t$ be 2 non-adjacent nodes in the graph $G$. We write as $p_l(s,t,G)$ the maximum internal paths disjoint (as nodes) from $s$ to $t$ in graph $G$, the maximum length $l$ ($l \in \{1,...,|G|\}$). Also, we write $k_l(s,t,G)$ as the minimum cardinality of a set of nodes different from $s$ and $t$, by removing paths from the graph so there are no more paths from $s$ to $t$ of lenght at most l.

The first question is to demonstrate that the inequality $p_l(s,t,G) \le k_l(s,t,G)$ holds. (*)

Secondly, I need to prove that using the graph below, that in the (*) relation, the inequality can be strict.

The path is described here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSK6z.jpg

Comment: Don't ask the same question again if the first time doesn't work. I've seen this one exactly, remember the image as well. If it gets downvoted so much that you have to delete the question and ask again, maybe you should try changing your question

Comment: maybe you saw another person from my university

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $k_{l}(s,t,G) < p_{l}(s,t,G)$.

Let $S$ be an arbitrary set of vertices such that $|S| = k_{l}(s,t,G)$ and consider $G - S$. Notice that each vertex in $S$ can only remove at most one  of the vertex disjoint $(s,t)$-paths of length $l$. This is because the $(s,t)$-paths are vertex disjoint, so a vertex in $S$ belongs to either one path and the removal of that vertex destroys that path, or it doesn't belong to any of the paths.

Since we assumed $k_{l}(s,t,G) < p_{l}(s,t,G)$, and by the above statement, we must have a $(s,t)$-path of length $l$ in $G-S$. But since we picked an arbitrary $S$ such that $|S| = k_{l}(s,t,G)$, we have a contradiction.

Comment: so most of graph-theory problems are solved with contradictions ? thank you :)

Comment: lots of  graph theory questions are solved using contradiction or induction. Usually when you have something that involves maximum objects contradiction works well.